# Stream API group by enum

Tags: java, java-stream, grouping

I need some help with using Java Stream API

I have a list of objects, the object has ENUM-field {Song, Klip, Karaoke}

How I can sort my list into three separate lists by the Enum-field. I know how I can do this using three streams (`list.filter().collect` three times) but I think it's not the best way.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please create some examples. Also, show the code of your other approach. It will then be easy for us to understand what you want to achieve and easier to provide help in finding a better solution ([ask]).

Comment: Are you sure you want to tag the question with *lightweight-stream-api*? This is a special external library which has nothing to do with the regular Stream API that came with Java 8. If you meant the latter, use the *stream* tag instead.

Comment: how i can change my post????

Comment: Hit the [edit] link beneath your question. You may want to take the [tour].

Comment: thanks for your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use `Collectors.groupingBy`, which returns a `Map`. As you did not provide any classes, i assumed the following:

```
enum SomeEnum {
    SONG,
    KLIP,
    KARAOKE
}

static class SomeClass {

    SomeEnum someEnum;

    public SomeClass(SomeEnum someEnum) {
        this.someEnum = someEnum;
    }

    public SomeEnum getSomeEnum() {
        return someEnum;
    }
}
```

Then you can simply use:

```
List<SomeClass> list = Stream.of(
            new SomeClass(SomeEnum.SONG),
            new SomeClass(SomeEnum.SONG),
            new SomeClass(SomeEnum.KLIP),
            new SomeClass(SomeEnum.KARAOKE),
            new SomeClass(SomeEnum.KARAOKE))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

// this is what you are looking for
Map<SomeEnum, List<SomeClass>> map = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(SomeClass::getSomeEnum));
```

It makes sense to use a `Map` instead of three differenct `List` objects.

Comment: Note that OP tagged the question with *lightweight-stream-api*, not *stream*. It may be possible that he does not talk about the regular Stream API which came with Java 8. In that case your answer is invalid.

Comment: @Zabuza If thats the case, i have to delete my answer.

Comment: i have tried this approach it works perfact , thanks one more time!!!!!